# Without using interrupts produce a rising sawtooth waveform

Tags: c, waveform, nios, oscilloscope

Here I need to output a waveform on oscilloscope in C which should in a rising sawtooth waveform.I am not sure if my code is correct. Any help or suggestions?

```
while(1)
{
    for (i = 1; i < 360; i++);

    // Check to see if status.TRDY is 1
    while(*(base+2) & 0x40 != 1);

    // while shift register is not empty
    // Make the sawtooth pattern
    if (saw == 0x1fff){
        saw = 0x1000;
    }
    else {
        saw = saw+1; 
    }
    // transmit sawtooth to the oscilloscope
    *(base+1) = saw;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run the code ?

Comment: I can't compile it before I get to the lab, and before lab we have to be sure it works so I am confused with my code if its doing the rite thing

Comment: @user4186509 you have no means to try your code?

Comment: Note: 1) Interesting that `for (i = 1; i < 360; i++);` does 359 loops. 2) `saw` is not initialized.

Comment: No unfortunately not. thats why looking forward for some help

Comment: saw = 0x1000 and does 305 there is a typo

Comment: Will not work - infinite loop `while(*(base+2) & 0x40 != 1);`

Comment: what do you suggest on that?

Comment: @user4186509 `while(*(base+2) & 0x40 != 1)` --> Anding with 0x40 will give a result of 0 or 0x40, both of which do not equal 1.  What do you think the result should be compared to, certainly not 1  (GTG)

Comment: you are rite but I am not sure what to compare it with

Comment: Not only does `for (i = 1; i < 360; i++);`  iterate only 359 times (as @chux commented), but it iterates the empty statement `;` 359 times.

Comment: `while(*(base+2) & 0x40 != 1);` needs brackets because `!=` has higher precedence than `&`, so use `while((*(base+2) & 0x40) != 1);`

Comment: got it. So do i need to make any changes in for (i = 1; i < 360; i++);?

Comment: It should probably be while(*(base+2) & 0x40 == 0) or else != 0, depending on what flag state you desire.  But you should probably be using a pointer to volatile to access memory mapped IO.

Comment: NO @Chris, it would be `while((*(base+2) & 0x40) == 0)` to override operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

This only tidies up the OP's posted code. It does not answer how to program the DAC. OP is using a 16-bit amplitude value but his register addressing suggests 8-bit registers - perhaps two writes are needed.

I suggest you also need function arguments defining the period of the sawtooth wave, and the number of steps. You also need an exit condition. I leave these points to you.

@Chris Stratton also commented that the I/O port should be the correct language type.

```
#define MINSAW  0x1000
#define MAXSAW  0x1FFF

unsigned *base = (unsigned *)0xD000;  // "insert your value"

int main()  {
    unsigned saw, i;
    while(1) {
        for (i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
            // ratio the waveform amplitude
            saw = MINSAW + i * (MAXSAW - MINSAW) / 359;

            // Check to see if status.TRDY is 1
            while((*(base+2) & 0x40) != 0x40);

            // transmit sawtooth to the oscilloscope
            *(base+1) = saw;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```